# Restructured database, using SQL in phpmyadmin to move data around

Tags: php, cakephp

I've recently been working on normalizing and restructuring my database to make it more effective in the long run. Currently I have around 500 records, and obviously I don't want to lose the users data.

I assume SQL through phpmyadmin is the easiest way to do this?

So let me give you guys an example

In my old table I would have something like this

```
records //this table has misc fields, but they are unimportant right now
id | unit |
1  | g    |
```

With my new one, I have it split apart 3 different tables.

```
records
id 
1

units
id | unit
1  |  g

record_units
id | record_id | unit_id
1  | 1         | 1
```

Just to be clear, I am not adding anything into the units table. The table is there as a reference for which id to store in the record_units table

As you can see it's pretty simple. What moved in the second table is that I started using an index table to hold my units, since they would be repeated quite often. I then store that unit id, and the pairing record id in the record_units table, so I can later retrieve the fields.

I am not incredibly experienced with SQL, though i'd say I know average. I know this operation would be quite simple to do with my cakephp setup, because all my associations are already setup, but I can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to copy related records from your old table to the new tables, in which case you can use something like this

```
UPDATE units u
INNER JOIN records r
    ON u.id=r.id
SET u.unit = r.unit
```

This will copy the unit type from your old table to the matching id in the new units table and then you can do something similare on your 3rd table